# vertices smaller than sprite when rendered on iPhone screen

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am using vertex helper to get the edges of my sprites. I am using Cocos2d + Box2d on the iPhone. The problem I am getting is that the debug draw on the device I am testing on comes up but the vertices rendered or shown is smaller than my sprites even after tracing the edges of the sprites carefully and using the same sprite.

OK here is a screen shot of the problem!

[image]

The green triangle is supposed to fit with the edges of the sprite. Also this is the code I used:

This is the GLESDebugDraw code

```
    - (void)setupDebugDraw {
debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw(PTM_RATIO* [[CCDirector   sharedDirector]    
contentScaleFactor]);
world->SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);
debugDraw->SetFlags(b2DebugDraw::e_shapeBit);
```

}

```
       #import "Box2DSprite.h"
    @interface Stalag :Box2DSprite {

b2World *world;
}
- (id)initWithWorld:(b2World *)world atLocation:(CGPoint)location;

@end

#import "Stalag.h"



@implementation Stalag
- (void)createBodyAtLocation:(CGPoint)location {
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
bodyDef.position = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO,
                          location.y/PTM_RATIO);
self.body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
body->SetUserData(self);
b2PolygonShape shape;


int num = 8;
b2Vec2 verts[] = {
    b2Vec2(36.8f / 100.0, -79.2f / 100.0),
    b2Vec2(10.3f / 100.0, 33.2f / 100.0),
    b2Vec2(1.8f / 100.0, 80.6f / 100.0),
    b2Vec2(-4.6f / 100.0, 84.5f / 100.0),
    b2Vec2(-8.5f / 100.0, 80.3f / 100.0),
    b2Vec2(-22.6f / 100.0, 19.4f / 100.0),
    b2Vec2(-31.8f / 100.0, -45.6f / 100.0),
    b2Vec2(-37.5f / 100.0, -75.7f / 100.0)
};
shape.Set(verts, num);

b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.shape = &shape;
fixtureDef.density = 1000.0;
body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
}
- (id)initWithWorld:(b2World *)theWorld atLocation:(CGPoint)location {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    world = theWorld;
    [self setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache                              
sharedSpriteFrameCache]     spriteFrameByName:@"hill.png"]];
    gameObjectType = kStalagupType;
    [self createBodyAtLocation:location];
}
return self;
   }
    @end
```

Please can anyone tell me what do I do and what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Provide some code and screenshots please. Your question can not be answered in current form

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the correction. I have added the codes and the image in question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying vertices coordinates you are dividing it by a "magic number" 100. Actually it is your PixelToMetersRatio (PTM_RATIO in cocos examples). Also you are using box2d debug draw. And when creating debug draw class your must pass PTM_RATIO in it's constructor. I think you are passing another number there (not 100). Does it solve the problem ?

Comment: thanks for your reply but  now I am confused...I don't really understand what you are saying.

Comment: @Zaki: please show the code where you are creating GLES_debugDraw

Comment: @Zaki: The problem is that you are passing diffirent value in it's constructor. Just try pass 100. And everything will be ok. But the best way will be to use PTM_RATIO instead of 100 when creating vertices

Comment: thanks a million. I have used PTM_RATIO and it worked. I think I have to go read more on this stuff. Once again thanks for your help.